# Convert dictionary of lists to a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I was try to find the same question like i want, i did not figure out. I try to learn python dictionary of list and convert into CSV file. Tha case is like this. i was try to create a header for a keys and i was try to create a data as value.

```
header_column = ["id", "data"]
text = ["1, first", "2, second", "3, thrid"]
for k in header_column:
    a = {k:text}
    insert = open('sample.csv', 'wb')
    insert.write(str(a))
```

On the csv, i want like :

```
id data
1  First
2  Second
3  Thrid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to use a dictionary? You can use the `csv` module and write those lists directly.

```
import csv

header_column = ["id", "data"]
text = ["1, first", "2, second", "3, third"]

with open('sample.tsv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(header_column)
    for l in text:
        writer.writerow(l.split(', '))
```

This works as expected, giving

```
id  data
1   first
2   second
3   third
```

Do note for excel to understand that your code is tab separated, you need to save it as a `.tsv` file.

Comment: how do you always manage to get an answer in so fast?! just as I start typing, yours will come through :p

Comment: @JoeIddon haha Sorry about that. I'm good at touch typing I guess :p

Comment: I try your code, but when i use .csv file, the result it's not like i want, but when i change with .tsv file, it's working/ But, Why .tsv file? it's cannot work for .csv file ??

Comment: @Scarlettstone Because! Excel sees the file extension and assumes the delimiter. That's why. Anyways, please do feel free to mark accepted if it helped.

Comment: Thank you, now it's working for me. i was try to improve to still using csv and It's working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to iterate through your list and write each line row-by-row.  This prevents the creation of your dictionary which doubles the memory requirement from the size of your list.

I've elected not to use the `csv` module and just write to the file directly given that the values you are writing to the file are already parsed as strings (except for the header, which needs to joined as a string).

```
header_column = ...
text = ...
with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(", ".join(header_column) + '\n')
    for row in text:
        f.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: Hey, it's pretty work. But, the header data it's not show and it's looping to much, almost every data have double data.

Comment: Works for me with the sample data.

Comment: oh my god, im sorry, the true text variable is text = ["1, 'first' ", "2, 'second' ", "3, 'third' "]. Whether this sign (') has an effect ??

Comment: Still worked for me, e.g. Row 1: `1, 'first'`.  Any chance your data is missing a single quotation which would then throw everything off?  E.g. `["1, 'first", "2, 'second'"]`

Answer (score 0):

I am a simple soul. There is no inherent need to use advanced techniques.

```
>>> header_column = ["id", "data"]
>>> text = ["1, first", "2, second", "3, thrid"]
>>> with open('sample.csv', 'w') as sample:
...     n = sample.write(' '.join(header_column)+'\n')
...     for item in text:
...         n = sample.write(item.replace(',', '')+'\n')
```

Edit: Slightly altered code in response to comment. Note additional `.replace("'", '')` in the second write statement.

```
>>> with open('sample.csv', 'w') as sample:
...     n = sample.write(' '.join(header_column)+'\n')
...     for item in text:
...         n = sample.write(item.replace(',', '').replace("'", '')+'\n')
```

Comment: I was try your code, but the result not like i want, becouse the result is the text varibale it's should be split on two column, id and data. but the all of text variable just show in 1 column.

Comment: Worked for me with the data supplied in the question.

Comment: oh my god, im sorry, the true text variable is text = ["1, 'first' ", "2, 'second' ", "3, 'third' "]. Whether this sign (') has an effect ??

Answer (score -1):

you import numpy just `pip -install numpy`

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,first], [2,second], [3,third] ])
numpy.savetxt("sample.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```